# Live query performance monitoring in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We use the following to measure performance of query in ORACLE,

```
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(
   sql_id => '&sql_id',
   type => 'TEXT',
   report_level => ALL) as report
from dual;
```

Can someone suggest how should I achieve the above outcome in Postgresql

Comment: There is no equivalent in Postgres.

Comment: is there any way to measure live query performance measurement in Postgresql

Comment: There is a 3rd party extension: https://github.com/StarfishStorage/explain-running-query